# Application crashes without error or close event

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, plotly

```py
version
pytnon 3.9
PyQtWebEngine   5.15.3  5.15.4
PyQtWebEngine-Qt    5.15.2  5.15.2
pandas  1.2.2   1.3.1
pip 21.0.1  21.2.3
plotly  4.14.3  5.1.0
paramiko    2.7.2   2.7.2
```

I am currently making GUI program which can view the database and plots it.
Program offers search for sample, the user can load the `sub_from` by double clicking `self.search_result` table. The code below is my code for the `main_form`.
The problem is

1. When multiple `sub_form` are loaded, sometimes all `sub_form` crashes except for the last one.
2. When I plot the plot multiple times, (as shown in the image) the `main_form` crashes. if the `main_form` is the parent of `sub_form`, they both crash. It crashes when I browse plots multiple times (roughly more than 10 times) (Apologies for not showing the whole view, it is our lab's project) [image]
3. No debug errors or closeEvent doesn't trigger when they crash

I use plotly and convert it into html, using QWebEngineView to plot. The file is open from remote directory, using paramiko, sftp connection. How can I fix this problem?

```py
class main_form(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, username, password, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        # Setting the position and size of the UI
        self.ui = uic.loadUi(os.path.abspath('source/main_form.ui'), self)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 1150, 574)

        # Error dialog
        self.error_dialog = QtWidgets.QErrorMessage()

        # initial_functions
        self.authority_setting()
        self.init_panel_tab(0)
        self.init_logbook_tab()
        self.logbook_table_view.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)



        # Search tab
        self.periodic_table_is_open = True
        self.search_result.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)

        self.periodic_table.setCurrentIndex(0)

        # Upload tab
        self.init_upload_tab()
        self.left_panel_summary_button_clicked()


        self.last_clicked_panel_button = self.left_panel_tab_button_0
        self.prevButtonSearch.setEnabled(False)
        self.nextButtonSearch.setEnabled(False)
        self.ui.show()


    def open_sample_window(self, item):
        row = item.row()
        model = self.search_result.model()
        index = model.index(row, 0)
        sample_id = int(model.data(index))
        sample_window = sub_form(string, string, string,string, parent=None)  #None & self, both crashes
```

The code below is **sub_form**

```py
class sub_form(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, string, string, string,string, parent):
        # UI_setting
        self.sample_id = sample_id
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = uic.loadUi(os.path.abspath('source/Sample_form.ui'), self)
        
        
        data_plot.show_fig()

        self.authority_setting()

        
        self.error_dialog = QtWidgets.QErrorMessage()
        self.ui.show()
        self.current_plot = ""
    def result_file_list_view_double_clicked(self, index = None):
        if index == None:
            index = self.result_file_list_view.selectionModel().selectedIndexes()

        file_name = self.result_file_list_view.model().itemData(index)[0]
        full_remote_file_name = remote name

        if self.current_plot == full_remote_file_name:
            pass
        else:
            with self.sftp_connection_open() as con_sftp:
                html = data_plot.visualize_remote_data_to_plot(con_sftp, full_remote_file_name)
                self.result_plot_view.setHtml(html)
            self.current_plot = full_remote_file_name
```

```
def visualize_remote_data_to_plot(con_SFTP, remote_path):
    with con_SFTP.open(remote_path, "r") as f:
        html = show_XRD_plot_form_file(f)
        condition = f.readline()
        df = pd.read_csv(f, delim_whitespace=True, names=["2Theta", "peak"])
        if len(df) > 0:
            fig = px.line(df, x="2Theta", y="peak")
            fig.update_layout(
                xaxis_title="2Theta",
                yaxis_title="peak",
                template='plotly_white'
            )
            return fig_to_html(fig)
        else:
            return "No data"
```

I made an simple example that has same error as this,

[image]
The ui design is very simple, and their signal functions are as written on the button
the widget is promoted into the `QWebEngineView`.
[image]
left side: `main_form`, right side: `sub_form`

Here are my code

> Python Code
>
> `main_form`

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from sub_form import sub_form

class main_form(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        # Setting the position and size of the UI
        self.ui = uic.loadUi(os.path.abspath('sample.ui'), self)
        self.ui.show()
        # Search tab
    @pyqtSlot()
    def browse(self):
        sub_form()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print("closed")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_form()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

`sub_form`

```
import os
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic, QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly


class sub_form(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # UI_setting
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, None)
        self.ui = uic.loadUi(os.path.abspath('plot.ui'), self)
        self.ui.show()
        self.a = 0
    @pyqtSlot()
    def plot(self):
        self.a += 1
        df = pd.DataFrame([[self.a+1,2],[self.a * self.a,4]], columns=["x","y"])
        fig = px.line(df, x="x", y="x")
        fig.update_layout(
            template='plotly_white'
        )
        config = {'doubleClick': 'reset', 'displaylogo': False, 'scrollZoom': True}
        html = '<html><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script></head><body>'
        html += plotly.offline.plot(fig, output_type='div', include_plotlyjs='cdn', config=config)
        html += '</body></html>'
        self.widget.setHtml(html)
```

> UI
>
> `sample.ui`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>313</width>
    <height>260</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>100</x>
      <y>100</y>
      <width>75</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>browse</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>313</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections>
  <connection>
   <sender>pushButton</sender>
   <signal>clicked()</signal>
   <receiver>MainWindow</receiver>
   <slot>browse()</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>396</x>
     <y>303</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>408</x>
     <y>408</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
 </connections>
 <slots>
  <slot>browse()</slot>
 </slots>
</ui>
```

`plot.ui`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QWebEngineView" name="widget" native="true">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>50</x>
      <y>110</y>
      <width>701</width>
      <height>431</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>50</x>
      <y>40</y>
      <width>75</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>plot</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>QWebEngineView</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>qwebengineview.h</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections>
  <connection>
   <sender>pushButton</sender>
   <signal>clicked()</signal>
   <receiver>MainWindow</receiver>
   <slot>plot()</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>119</x>
     <y>72</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>299</x>
     <y>-79</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
 </connections>
 <slots>
  <slot>plot()</slot>
 </slots>
</ui>
```

How can I fix this?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: share the .ui files

Comment: I am not going to review external links, the MRE must be in your post.

Comment: @eyllanesc sorry to making you use your time, but I don't know how to upload .ui file in here except for uploading git link, and I uploaded it on my post.

Comment: The .ui is an .xml file so open it with any editor (such as a notepad) and copy the content

Comment: @eyllanesc I did, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have not assigned the objects to a variable causing the objects to be deleted. You have to change to:

```py
w = main_form()
```

and

```py
self.s = sub_form()
```

Comment: I have this similar issue where my application, (UI being constructed in Qt Designer and using QWebEngineView to plot Plotly Graphs) just crashes without any error in the command prompt. it only prints this message after getting crashed. "Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)" Usually it crashes when doing some actions on the plotly graphs like adding/removing legends or zoom in/out. Are you able to lend any help in this? I would really appreciate your time and effort.